# Need to delete duplicate records from a table with 30 columns

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, netezza

I need to delete the exact duplicate records from a table with 30 columns.
My data would look something as attached.Advance Thanks!![image]

Comment: The image is too large but too small

Comment: which exactly rows should be considered as duplicated? what is the condition? e.g. there should be repeating rows with the same colum1 and colum2 values

Comment: @Lithu T.V, took me a while to get what you mean, lol

Comment: Did you search first? Been answered many times.

Answer (score 1):

Your question I understood like this...

1) if you want to delete only one record from duplicate rows.In this case you need a column date with (current timestamp) in table

```
delete from tableName t1 where
t1.id in (SELECT     t2.id
         FROM         tableName t2
         where t1.id = t2.id and t1.date(timestamp) < t2.date(timestamp))
```

2) if you want delete complete duplicate rows

```
delete from tableName t1 where
t1.id in (SELECT     t2.id
         FROM         tableName t2
         group by t2.id
         having count(*) >1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This one should work:

```
delete from <table>
where rowid IN (
     SELECT LEAD(rowid) OVER (PARTITION BY <col1>, <col2>,...,<coln> ORDER BY NULL) 
     FROM <table>
);
```

And of course [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8f3f6/18)